# Get the data of a json response

Tags: c#, json

https://rbx.rocks/apis/user_items?u=Zinthetic

The response is json and i'm trying to get the \"stats\":{\"RAP\":\"270,924\"

I'm trying to get the RAP value so 270,924
Could you guys help me? thanks

Comment: m? what do you mean @Sнаđошƒаӽ

Comment: JObject jsonValue = JObject.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://rbx.rocks/apis/user_items?u=Shedletsky"));
                Console.WriteLine(jsonValue.GetValue("RAP"));

Comment: Tried that before but didn't work

Comment: JSON.Net will help you achieve this. For reference: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm .

Comment: string jsonValue = JObject.Parse(wc.DownloadString("https://rbx.rocks/apis/user_items?u=Shedletsky")).ToString();
                var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonValue);
                string timeZone = data["RAP"].Value<string>();
                return matches.ToString();

Comment: didn't work @Dimitar

Comment: @Kyle "m" was just typo, was typing that comment in phone, and in Gboard "?" is under the key "m", so...
Anyway, you should add the codes you tried with in the question itself, not in comments. If you don't, expect some more downvotes. Sorry if it sounds rude, but that's how [SO] works.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Try this

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
foreach (var item in data.inventory)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.RAP);
}
```

And the classes will be :

```
public class Inventory
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RAP { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public List<int> UserAssetIDs { get; set; }
    public List<object> Serials { get; set; }
    public object SerialNumTotal { get; set; }
    public int Copies { get; set; }
    public int AssetID { get; set; }
    public string ImageLink { get; set; }
    public string ItemLink { get; set; }
    public string Img { get; set; }
    public int Demand { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
}

public class Stats
{
    public string RAP { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public bool verified { get; set; }
    public bool is_scammer { get; set; }
    public int percentagechange { get; set; }
    public int ecostatus { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> rappoints { get; set; }
    public List<List<object>> valuepoints { get; set; }
    public int history_points { get; set; }
    public string Rank { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string reason { get; set; }
    public List<Inventory> inventory { get; set; }
    public Stats stats { get; set; }
}
```